# Number of comparisons Merge Sort of unknown size array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, recurrence

Given an array of n distinct numbers, where n = 2^k, how do I find and prove the minimum and maximum number of comparisons?

The comparisons would be between the distinct elements.

I have seen some questions on SO but doesn't seem to match what I'm looking for.

Comment: This seems to be a homework question. So please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions first and edit your question accordingly ...

Comment: BTW, this is pretty easy if you want a code. Just have a "static" counter variable in your merge sort function and for every comparison, have it incremented by 1.
If you need a logical solution, it is simple divide and conquer...best and worst case O(n log n). Its pretty obvious if you know how merge sort works. Also, I think googling would help you more.

Comment: @vish4071: the counter solution does not work. Unless you try all permutations, you are not sure to cover the best and worst cases. For n=2^k, this is quickly unpractical. And even if you manage, you'll get a bunch of numbers, not a formula.

Comment: The number of possible comparisons between n numbers is n.(n-1)/2.

Comment: @derpirscher I will edit my question to show what I've done. Forgot to add that in.

Comment: @vish4071 I do not need the codes. This is for a design and analysis of algo subject. Also, i appreciate it but that is not what i'm asking for :') I dont need the overall time complexity of Big O but the number of min/max comparisons of merge sort..

Comment: This also appears to be a computer science question, since you're looking for a proof instead of a computer program. [cs.se] is probably a better place.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I might be missing or forgetting something here, but the way merge-sort works, in a randomised or sorted array, or anything in between, the approach is exactly the same. Divide into halves until you have singular array elements and then compare and put them into their place for a sorted array.

I believe number of comparisons will be same for all arrays of same size. No?

Comment: @RaymondChen noted on that for future questions, thanks!

Comment: @vish4071, no, there is this aspect: when during the merge all of the elements of one of the two subarrays have been put in their sorted position (ie. they are less then the currently inspected value in the other subarray), then the rest of the other subarray can be copied without performing any further comparisons on them.

Comment: @vish4071: without looking into the algorithm and thinking, you cannot be sure that this is always true unless you try every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the comparisons happen during the backtracking step out of recursion, when two adjacent sorted subarrays are merged.

In the best case the two sorted subarrays (each of size ) can just be concatenated as they are, where one comes after the other. In that case the  comparisons are between all of the values of one subarray with a single value of the other, so that gives us  number of comparisons.

In the worst case the two sorted subarrays need to be interwoven, such that the very last comparison is between the last two values in both subarrays. In total that makes 2−1 comparisons.

Now we need to add up the comparisons made at all stages (partition sizes).

The **best** case number of comparisons for an array with  elements (2) is then:

0 + 1(/2) + 2(/4) + 4(/8) + ... + (/2)⋅1 = (/2)log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub> = 2<sup>−1</sup>

The **worst** case number of comparisons is the double of that (cf the 2 term above), **minus**:

/2 + /4 + /8 + ... + 1 =  − 1

...so we get: log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub> −  + 1 = (−1)2 + 1

### In Summary

Best case: 2<sup>−1</sup>

Worst case: (−1)2 + 1

Comment: Oh...wow!! This makes so much sense, thanks for this explanation. I always thought that for Merge sort, we Divide into halves until we have singular array elements and then compare and put them into their place for a sorted array. So number of comparisons will be same for all arrays of same size.